# Add items to Listbox

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox

How can I add combo box items to a list box? But, I need to show only one item of the combo box at once. When I change again in the combo box, only the selected item have to be added to the Listbox. Please help

Comment: Show what you tried!

Comment: private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());           
        }

Comment: this adds everything we select :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the SelectedItem of comboBox to the ListBox on the SelectionChanged event

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<String> cmboSource = new List<string>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cmboSource.Add("item1");
            cmboSource.Add("item2");
            cmboSource.Add("item3");
            comboBox1.DataSource = cmboSource;

        }
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens when we have added items to the combo box with the icon in the form design :\

Comment: It does the same way

Comment: you got the answer?